# What does it mean to serialize/ deserialize a session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, serialization, deserialization, passport.js

In reading about Rails, I encountered the phrase "rails will read the cookie and deserialize the session", but I don't know what the second part means.  I've googled and searched SO, and found explanations of *how* to do it.  For example,

```
# Serialize using Marshal.dump - Binary
serialized_object = Marshal.dump(hello)

# DeSerialize using Marshal.load
hello = Marshal.load(serialized_object)
```

But I haven't seen an explanation of *what* is being done or *why* you would want to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From further reading, I've gathered that serialization and deserialization *in general* refer to the conversion of structured data into binary in order to be transmitted electronically (serialization), and undoing that transformation (deserialization).  So presumably serializing/ deserializing a session refers to the `session` or the aggregate of session data going through that process.